# Splitting text in PowerShell using content delimiter as filename

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to split a txt transcription into single files, one for each folio.

The file is marked as `[c. 1r]`,`[c. 1v]` ... `[c. 7v]` and so on.

Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238016/text-file-splitting-in-multiple-files-by-content-in-powershell) I was able to create a PowerShell script that does the magic with a regex that match each page delimiter , but I seem totally unable to use the regex in order to give proper names to the pages. With this code

```
$InputFile = "input.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$a = 1
while (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($Line -match "\[c\. .*?\]") {
        $OutputFile = "MySplittedFileNumber$a$Matches.txt"
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

all the files are named with `MySplittedFileNumber1System.Collections.Hashtable.txt` instead of the match, with `"$Matches[0]"` I'm told that the variable does not exist or has been filtered by `-Exclude`.

All my attempts of setting the `$regex` before executing seems to go nowhere, can someone point me on how to get the result filenames formatted as `MySplittedFileNumber[c. 1r].txt`.

Using just a partial match as `\[(c\. .*?)\]` would be even better, but once I know how to retrieve the match, I bet I can find the solution.
I can do the variable `1r` `1v` setting in `$a`, somehow, but I'd rather use the one inside the txt file, since some folio may have been misnumbered in the manuscript and I need to retain this.

Content of original `input.txt`:

```
> [c. 1r]
Text paragraph
text paragraph
...
Text paragraph
[c. 1v]
Text paragraph
text paragraph
...
Text paragraph
[c. 2r]
Text paragraph
text paragraph
...
Text paragraph
```

Desired result:

Content of `MySplittedFileNumber[c. 1r].txt`:

```
> [c. 1r]
    Text paragraph
    text paragraph
    ...
    Text paragraph
```

Content of `MySplittedFileNumber[c. 1v].txt`:

```
> [c. 1v]
    Text paragraph
    text paragraph
    ...
    Text paragraph
```

Content of `MySplittedFileNumber[c. 2r].txt`:

```
> [c. 2r]
    Text paragraph
    text paragraph
    ...
    Text paragraph
```

Comment: Just my first guess, but did you try: `$OutputFile = "MySplittedFileNumber$a$($Matches[0]).txt"`

Comment: Please show a meaningful sample of your input and the desired output.

Comment: @Tomalak `$Matches` does'nt need to be defined. It gives the Value that matched with your last use of `-match`.

Comment: @Paxz Oh, nice. I actually didn't know that.

Comment: I updated the question with the examples, thank for your suggestion @Tomalak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it and with a little change it worked:

```
$InputFile = "input.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$a = 1
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {

    If ($Line -match "\[c\. .*?\]") {
        $OutputFile = "MySplittedFileNumber$a$($Matches[0]).txt"
        $a++
    }    
    Out-File -LiteralPath "<yourFolder>\$OutputFile" -InputObject $Line -Append
}
```

1. To call a position of an array while in `""` you have to format the variable like this `$($array[number])`
2. To write to the file, you should give the Fullpath and not just the Filename.

Comment: Thank you, it is working but the "Out-File - LiteralPath" seems to give me some problems with unicode characters I did not had with "Add Content". Any idea?

Comment: @Lila Try to play around with the `-Encoding` option of `Out-File`.

Comment: After having some issues, I decided that for me it was easier to convert the original to utf8 (was Ansi at beginning) and this solved the problem.

Comment: @Lila Thats also an option :P If the answer was correct, don't forget to mark it as correct ;)

Comment: For those interested in using just a part of the regex, I simply used positive lookbehind and lookahead like this `$Line -match "(?<=\[c\. +).*?(?=\].*?)"` in order to get only the folio number and r-v. Since we are planning to adapt it to several transcriptions, it was well worth the scripting time!

Answer (score 0):

From Version 3 on PowerShells `Get-Content` cmdlet has the `-Raw` parameter which allows to read a file as a whole into a string you can then split into chunks with a regular exression (using a [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) ).

The very same RegEx can be use to grep the section name and insert into the destination file name.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51421567.ps1
##
$RE = [RegEx]'(?=(\[c\. \d+[rv]\]))'

$Sections = (Get-Content '.\input.txt' -raw) -split $RE -ne ''

ForEach ($Section in $Sections){
    If ($Section -Match $RE){
        $Section | Out-File -LiteralPath ("MySplittedFileNumber{0}.txt" -f $Matches[1])
    }
}
```